# For what vectors $a$ (if any), is this function injective?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

For $z \in \mathbb R^d$, let $f(z) = \sum_{i=1}^d e^{-z_i}$. Also, for a given vector $a = (a_k) \in \mathbb R^d$, let
$$
S_i(x) = \sum_{k=i}^d a_k x_k, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R^d.
$$
We also let $S(x) = (S_1(x),\dots,S_d(x)) \in \mathbb R^d$.

For what vectors $a$ (if any), is the function $x\mapsto f(S(x))$ injective over $\mathbb R_+^d = \{x =(x_i) \in \mathbb R^d:\; x_i \ge 0, \forall i\}$?

Of special interest are the cases where $a = (1)$ the vector of all ones, and the case $a = (k/(k+1))$.